# How to test and debug programs when input data is very large

Tags: testing

When developing programs whose input is of reasonable size, it is possible to develop edge cases and discover the errors present in the program. But when the input for a program is very large (for example, say, programs for image processing), what is the best method to debug?

Answer (score 2):

maybe delta debugging method helps you. refer to [this](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~su/theses/GM-thesis.pdf) article

Comment: Delta debugging is not about discovering bugs, it is about already discovered bugs and then minimizing the needed input. Also, this needn't be edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Also on delta-debugging, I think it is important to mention the first paper on the subject: https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/xyzhang/fall07/Papers/delta-debugging.pdf

Comment: Delta debugging is not about discovering bugs, it is about already discovered bugs and then minimizing the needed input. Also, this needn't be edge cases.

Comment: A failure is not a bug, but a symptom of a bug. Delta debugging is about already discovered failures and then minimizing the failure-inducing input, to facilitate the job of the developer to discover the respective bug. Delta debugging is all about discovering bugs.

Answer (score 0):

### How to test

[Fuzz Testing (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) can help identifying yet undicovered bugs.

If you have source code available, you can use tools that do *white box testing*. [Agitar](http://www.agitar.com/solutions/products/automated_junit_generation.html) is such a tool for Java. It will identify conditions (like `if` statements) in your code and create code to test edge cases and make sure all paths are covered.

### How to debug

Once you have identified a problem in your code, you might want to apply the delta debugging algorithm as mentioned by others before. This helps you minimize the input to a minimum which still reproduces the bug. Fuzz testing and white box test generation do not guarantee a minimum input.

Other than that, debugging heavily depends on the programming language and tools you have available, so I consider that part of the question as too broad to answer.